# A lot of textboxes, how to manage? MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox

I writing some App, to input 64 byte for sending over some communication standard. App must have in each textbox one byte, so I need 64 textboxes. This means that I must make 64 "NotifyPropertyChanged" getter/setter functions. Or is any better way?

If is no better way, how to manage all this functions? Paste only this 64 functions in special class file and connect to my viewmodel? And how to connect it? As instance or something else?

In total I will need 64 textboxes for sending and then also 64 (textblocks) for received message. Yes is possible to make everything in one textbox but I am not making decisions here :)

I also need restrict characters inputet into textboxes - 0-9 and A-F.

I am new in MVVM and WPF so sorry if this is stupid question. If any other question please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings support arrays, so just add an array in your view model:

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        private int[] _Vals = new int[64];
        public int[] Vals { get { return this._Vals; } }
    }
```

And bind each textbox to an element in your XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Vals[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Vals[1], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Vals[2], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Vals[3], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    ... etc ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks! How to restrict textboxes to accept only numbers and letter A-F (Hex)?

Comment: There [an article here](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/06/18/how-to-limit-or-prevent-characters-in-a-textbox-in-csharp/) showing an easy way to do it with MVVM for numbers but you can easily modify it to include hex characters. Technically this isn't MVVM, but it should be good enough for you to use at this stage.

Comment: One question. How later implement "Clear" function. Set "Vals = null;" or made this with new empty string? Or what is the best way? I try it both, but next time when I go into "Send" command to send (where I have "inputetmessage = Vals") is inputetmessage only "null" all the way to the end.

Comment: You can do that by implementing Erno de Weerd's suggestion below i.e. create a separate view model for each byte.

Comment: If I use Erno de Weerd's solution, where/how is better to check inputet data for "Hex letters". Take given array into one string and check with regex? And will for Erno de Weerd's solution if I must have textboxes in two lines (now I made this with grid and define two rows). Sorry for stupid question but I amm pretty new in this WPF thing

Answer (score 1):

Consider making a ViewModel for one byte (containing the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged) and adding 64 instances of this to a collection.

Then you can use a ItemsControl to show the TextBoxes and use the collection to get all the bytes.

To restrict the textboxes to allow for Hex values only you can use a combination of a ValueConverter and handeling the keydown on the textboxes.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const int numberOfBytes = 64;
    private NumbersViewmodel numbers = new NumbersViewmodel(numberOfBytes);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = numbers;
    }

}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public class NumbersViewmodel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> numbers;

    public ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> Numbers
    {
        get { return numbers; }
        set
        {
            if (numbers != value)
            {
                numbers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Numbers");
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand SendNumbers
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public NumbersViewmodel(int numberOfNumbers)
    {
        sendNumbers = new SimpleCommand(SendNumbersExecuted);
        this.Numbers = new ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++)
        {
            this.Numbers.Add(new NumberViewModel());
        }
    }

    private void SendNumbersExecuted()
    {
        ///DoSomethingWith(Numbers);
    }
}

public class NumberViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private byte number;

    public byte Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            if (number != value)
            {
                number = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("Number");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action execute;
    public SimpleCommand(Action execute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (execute != null && CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            execute();
        }
    }
}

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Command="{Binding SendBytes}">Send the bytes</Button>

</Grid>
```